# QPushButton Focusing Behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

When creating a standard QPushButton it is given complete focus if there are no other Widgets in the window. However, even if there are other widgets, once clicked the button stays focused. Here is an image to show the behaviour:

[image: blue glow on button]

If I click the button and move my mouse out of the button, it also has this focus. The method tied to the button does not execute however, and this is intended behaviour. The focus is not. It should only be focused like this when clicked, and should revert back to it's normal state once it is no longer being held down. See here:

[image: unfocused]

I have tried various things to try and fix this, such as the `setFocus(False)` method, the `setAutoFocus()` method and also the `setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)` method. This has only given a little bit of success. Yes, the button is not focused now, but it never gains focus; hence "NoFocus". This is what the button looks like when clicked if I have the "NoFocus" parameter set:

[image: unfocused button]

Basically, I only want the button to have focus when clicked, and I want it to lose focus after it's clicked. In essence, to go back to how it looks in the second screenshot.

I'm using Antergos Arch Linux with KDE Plasma, so I'm hoping this isn't some kind of Qt library issue. I can't find anything about this online, for PyQt5 or otherwise.

Thanks.

Edit: Here is the code for the button:

```
self.play_pause_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
self.play_pause_button.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
```

Edit 2: Here is a full piece of example code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.resize(640, 480)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
    button.setText('Push me!')

    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

    layout.addWidget(button)

    window.setLayout(layoutB)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is what the example looks like on my system:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the post.

Comment: Can you post a complete example that can be ran? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added a full code example.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with qt. The behaviour is determined by the widget-style installed on your system.

Comment: It only happens with PyQt though. Other Qt apps are completely fine.

Comment: try with `app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: That displays it correctly, although with a different theme of course. As mentioned above it's related to the theme, but I wonder why it's only affecting PyQt...

Comment: @Eamonn. How did you install pyqt? Did you use pip, or your distro's packages? The former would use a wheel that contains a separate copy of the qt libraries, which might explain the differences you see with other qt apps on your system.

Comment: PyQt came preinstalled with Antergos. The only difference I see is that the button focus behaviour. Everything renders with the system theme, which it would not if I used `sudo pip3 install pyqt5`.

Comment: @Eamonn. When you say "other Qt apps", do you mean vanilla qt, or kde, or both? For example, how does the qt designer application behave? It's hard to see why this would only affect pyqt, since it is a pretty thin wrapper around the qt libraries.

Comment: I'm referring to both. As an example, Krita, Kdenlive, Kwrite, etc. The QtDesigner behaves as expected. See here: https://imgur.com/a/JxN0ZS0